# What is the most efficient way to copy a two dimensional arrays of primitive type in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, copy

What is the most efficient way to copy a two dimensional arrays of primitive type in java?

Say I have a 2 dimensional array (or even multidimensional array) of some primitive type in Java and I'd like to make "clone" of it. What would be the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[][] B = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);
```

as in

```
int[][] A = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8,9}};

    int[][] B = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);
    for(int[] C: B)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(C));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wan a deep copy you'll need an extra loop

```
int[][] A = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8,9}};

int[][] b = new int[][a.length];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)b[i]=Arrays.copyOf(a[i], a[i].length);
```

recurse as needed

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I tried this, and when I altered b, A also got modified.